# draw a multicolor line with a CGPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-graphics, cgpath

below you see a code that draws a multicolor line each time drawMulticolorLine is called.

```
    void drawMulticolorLine
    {
        CGContextBeginPath(secondaryContext);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(secondaryContext, h, v);
        for( int i = 1; i < lineWidth; ++ )
        {
            SetStrokeColor(i);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(secondaryContext, h+i, v);
            CGContextDrawPath(secondaryContext, kCGPathFillStroke);
            CGContextMoveToPoint(secondaryContext, h+i, v);
        }
    }

    //a function that sets a different color for each i
    void SetStrokeColor(int i)
    {
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(secondaryContext,…
    }
```

the code above works but if i use it in real live, it is a perfomance killer. so i try to improve the drawing performance with the code below.

```
    void drawMulticolorLine
    {
        CGContextBeginPath(secondaryContext);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(secondaryContext, h, v);
        for( int i = 1; i < lineWidth; ++ )
        {
            SetStrokeColor(i);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(secondaryContext, h+i, v);
        }
        CGContextDrawPath(secondaryContext, kCGPathFillStroke);
    }

    //a function that sets a different color for each i
    void SetStrokeColor(int i)
    {
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(secondaryContext,…
    }
```

this code works with a good performance if the line color is always the same.

my issue now is that once CGContextDrawPath is called the whole line is drawn in the color of the last CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor.

is there a way that the path keeps the colors of every line segment that was added ?

any help is greatly appreciated.

cheers,
bzt

Comment: I'm no core-graphics guy, but would CGContextSetStrokePattern be useful to you?

Comment: no, i have thought about that already and a pattern doesn't work, because the colors set by SetStrokeColor are dynamic. every line that gets calculated has a different color for every i (line segment) and each completed line (after i==lineWidth) is then shifted vertical and a new line gets drawn ...

Answer (score 0):

recently played in playground, so sharing source code.

```
extension CGFloat {
    static func random() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    static func random() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red:   .random(),
                       green: .random(),
                       blue:  .random(),
                       alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
let copy: CGPath = ...
let image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: copy.boundingBoxOfPath.size).image { context in

    context.cgContext.setLineWidth(2)

    copy.applyWithBlock { element in
        switch element.pointee.type {
        case .moveToPoint:
            context.cgContext.move(to: element.pointee.points[0])
        case .addLineToPoint:
            context.cgContext.addLine(to: element.pointee.points[0])
            context.cgContext.setStrokeColor(UIColor.random().cgColor)
            context.cgContext.strokePath()
            context.cgContext.move(to: element.pointee.points[0])
        case .addQuadCurveToPoint:
            let controlPoint = element.pointee.points[0]
            let point = element.pointee.points[1]
            context.cgContext.addCurve(to: point, control1: controlPoint, control2: controlPoint)
            context.cgContext.setStrokeColor(UIColor.random().cgColor)
            context.cgContext.strokePath()
            context.cgContext.move(to: point)
        case .addCurveToPoint:
            let controlPoint1 = element.pointee.points[0]
            let controlPoint2 = element.pointee.points[1]
            let point = element.pointee.points[2]
            context.cgContext.addCurve(to: point, control1: controlPoint1, control2: controlPoint2)
            context.cgContext.setStrokeColor(UIColor.random().cgColor)
            context.cgContext.strokePath()
            context.cgContext.move(to: point)
        case .closeSubpath:
            context.cgContext.setStrokeColor(UIColor.random().cgColor)
            context.cgContext.strokePath()
        }
    }
}
```